# Angular2 bundling and minification

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, systemjs

ASP.NET (or gulp) will take care of bundling and minification. However, the problem i came across is rather different. Per Angular2's tutorials, the view HTML is embedded within the component itself. There is a way, using TypeScript, to separate that into a `.ts` and `.html` files. Here's how:

```
...
/// <reference path="./view-declaration.d.ts" />
...
import {html} from '/app.html!text';
...
@Component({
    ...
    template: html
})
...
```

And faking `.html` as a module in `view-declaration.d.ts` file:

```
declare module '/app.html!text' {
    var html:string;
    return default html;
}
```

This is using SystemJS with its text plugin. This will not generate `System.register` for `.html` files which means HTMLs can't be bundled along the transpiled `.js` files.

So questions is, how do you separate the HTML from JavaScript, but also be able to bundle them properly?

Also to note, this approach is just the same as setting the `templateUrl` on your component. Both of which defeat the purpose of bundling and reduction of server hits per component. The offered solution from Angular2 is to use string and set `template` on a component. This is pretty far from reality of junior developers and code reviews (yea not gonna get the whole code base in order to run and see if browser complains about a non-closed tag!).

Comment: Are you saying `templateUrl` doesn't work for you because it doesn't get bundled together?

Comment: The whole point of bundling is not to hit the server multiple times. So `templateUrl` is more useful for Dev environment, not production.

Comment: You could bundle the Html within the JS and everything if you used Webpack instead of SystemJS

Comment: @MarkPieszak out of curiosity, how would i do that with webpack? I'm thinking maybe i could switch to webpack and use the external Visual Studio tools to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you'll need to use `templateUrl` for development, but replace that with `template` during the bundling and minification. This is the gulp task for the job:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); //install 'gulp' via npm
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'); //install 'gulp-uglify' via npm
var concat = require('gulp-concat'); //install 'gulp-concat' via npm
var replace = require('gulp-replace'); //install 'gulp-replace' via npm
var fs = require("fs"); //already available in Visual Studio and of course NodeJS

gulp.task('bundle:js', function () {
    return gulp
        .src([
            "file1.js",
            "file2.js"
        ])
        .pipe(replace(/templateUrl.*\'/g, function (matched) {
            var fileName = matched.match(/\/.*html/g).toString();
            var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName, "utf8");
            return 'template:\'' + fileContent.replace(/\r\n/g, '') + '\'';
        }))
        .pipe(concat('file.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('my bundle folder'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('my bundle folder'));
});
```

This is to match `.html` files and the template URL, but it can be tweaked if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is gulp plugin which I think can solve your issue.
look at:
https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template

the advantage you keep having a clean html file using templateUrl during development. And this task can be part of your production\staging -minified - gulp build task.

e.g (Part of my build tasks!)

```
    var inlineNg2Template = require('gulp-inline-ng2-template');
    gulp.task('build-prod', ['build.lib'], function () {
    var tsProject = typescript.createProject('./tsconfig.json', {                         typescript: require('typescript') });
    var tsSrcInlined = gulp.src([webroot + '**/*.ts'], { base: webroot })
    .pipe(inlineNg2Template({ base: webroot }));
    return eventStream.merge(tsSrcInlined, gulp.src('Typings/**/*.ts'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(typescript(tsProject))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(webroot));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template file `app.html.ts` can export the html template as a string.

```
export const htmlTemplate = `
    <p>My app</p>
`;
```

Then your component (`app.component.ts`) can import the template inline.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { htmlTemplate } from './app.html';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: htmlTemplate,
})
...
```

This approach:

- allows for in-lining of templates at compilation, avoiding the additional network request that using "templateUrl" adds and allowing templates to be minified and bundled with other js
- allows templates to live in external files for code clarity and scaling
- can be easily migrated to a plain HTML file once Typescript "import file as string" functionality is in place
- allows Webstorm html syntax highlighting to still work correctly

[See blog from Angular University](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-run-angular-2-in-production-today/#awayofhandlinghtmltemplates)

Comment: Unfortunately with this approach you'll lose all html features that code editors offer, besides webstorm.